# Get all deviations from several unique values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a sheet with more than 100,000 row-entries. Its is structured like:

| Article Number | Article Name | Place | Number of Articles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 101 | 3920 |
| 99 | 42 | 95 | 1003 |

The "place" column is where the article is being distributed (sold) from. What I want to achieve now is too find where the distribution centers might have made a mistake in logging in the number of articles. The normal way to do this is by making filtering the excel table for each article and look at the number of articles for the specific distribution center. If a distribution center has much more than the average, the number of articles is likely not real.

For filtering I have used that only articles should be filtered that are twice as big as the 95% quantile. But thats just an idea.

I would like to find a solution without VBA, if thats not possible that would also be okay. As a result I want a list of all the articles which have significantly larger number of articles than the average article number of that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Determine_Outliers()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting RunTime -> Check the box

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim place As String
    Dim places As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim totals() As Double
    Dim instances() As Long
    Dim arrBound As Long: arrBound = -1
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Get Totals & Instances
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        place = ws.Cells(r, 3).Value
        If places.Exists(place) Then
            idx = places(place)
            instances(idx) = instances(idx) + 1
            totals(idx) = totals(idx) + ws.Cells(r, 4).Value
        Else
            arrBound = arrBound + 1
            places.Add place, arrBound
            ReDim Preserve instances(0 To arrBound)
            ReDim Preserve totals(0 To arrBound)
            instances(arrBound) = 1
            totals(arrBound) = ws.Cells(r, 4).Value
        End If
    Next r
     ' Get Average
    Dim avg() As Double
    ReDim avg(0 To arrBound)
    For r = 0 To arrBound
        avg(r) = totals(r) / instances(r)
    Next r
    
    ' Get Variance
    Dim variance() As Double
    ReDim variance(0 To arrBound)
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        idx = places(CStr(ws.Cells(r, 3).Value))
        variance(idx) = variance(idx) + (ws.Cells(r, 4).Value - avg(idx)) ^ 2
    Next r
    For r = 0 To arrBound
        variance(r) = (variance(r) / (instances(r) - 1)) ^ 0.5
    Next r
    
    ' 95% confidence Interval -> z = 1.96
    ' CI = avg +- z*s / (n)^.5
    Dim UCI() As Double
    ReDim UCI(0 To arrBound)
    Dim LCI() As Double
    ReDim LCI(0 To arrBound)
    For r = 0 To arrBound
        ' *** Mess around with the 1.96, your dataset and outlier size will drive how big you want the confidence interval to be ***
        UCI(r) = avg(r) + 1.96 * variance(r) / (instances(r) ^ 0.5)
        LCI(r) = avg(r) - 1.96 * variance(r) / (instances(r) ^ 0.5)
    Next r
    
    ' Color nofill
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(lastRow, 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    ' Flag Outliers
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        idx = places(CStr(ws.Cells(r, 3).Value))
        If ws.Cells(r, 4).Value > UCI(idx) Then
            ws.Cells(r, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf ws.Cells(r, 4).Value < LCI(idx) Then
            ws.Cells(r, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next r
    
    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Good Luck